# VPS Ubuntu server 18.04 // virtual host // website not loading

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, virtual, host

I have setup a website at a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04. I have only installed Apache and PHP and configured ufw to allow access through 80 and 443 ports.

At my registrar, since this actually is the main site for the server, I added the server ip for DNS: 192.188.78.105 and also modified nameserver to be ns1.justfitnessbooks.com and ns2.justfitnessbooks.com

FYI, ns1.xx and ns2.xxx work just fine because before this install, I had installed Vesta CP which installs a complete server package, and the site would load just fine, but it was impossible to use email with Vesta CP, so I uninstalled everything and started with a manual configuration.

My justfitnessbooks.com.conf file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin myemail@myserver.com
        ServerName justfitnessbooks.com
        ServerAlias www.justfitnessbooks.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/justfitnessbooks.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My justfitnessbooks.com.conf file inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin myemail@myserver.com
        ServerName justfitnessbooks.com
        ServerAlias www.justfitnessbooks.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/justfitnessbooks.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
192.188.78.105 justfitnessbooks.com
192.188.78.105 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#::1 justfitnessbooks.com
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Doing ls -la permissions for the site directory looks like this:

```
admin@server-12345:/var/www/html$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar  8 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar  8 01:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10918 Mar  8 01:53 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar  8 15:39 justfitnessbooks.com
admin@server-12345:/var/www/html$
```

I have restarted apache with systemctl restart apache2

And, when I check the host for justfitnessbooks.com I get the below message:

```
admin@server-12345:~$ host justfitnessbooks.com
justfitnessbooks.com has address 192.188.78.105
Host justfitnessbooks.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
admin@server-12345:~$
```

**What am I missing?** 
**Am I to modified anything related to ns1.xxx ns2.xxx at my server?**

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: A nameserver would usually be at `ns1.someisp.com`, not `ns1.thedomainnameiwanttolookup.com`. Also, an IP address starting 192.188 is so close to 192.168 that I have to ask you to confirm it. Finally, there is nothing responding to ping at 192.188.78.105.

Comment: Hello, the ns1.xx and ns2. configurations are fine because they worked when I installed Vesta CP which comes with Apache, php, etc, so I could browse the site with the Vesta CP installation, but it was impossible to use email so I uninstalled the Vesta CP package and started from scratch. Now, I am trying to do everything manually. The IPs provided are just samples IPs, not real IPs. Thaks for cooperation.